# How to start speechRecognize automatically when hearing a voice

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I want to build an android application that can start speechRecognize automatically when my phone "hearing" a sound. just like google launcher in android 4.4 that the google search can be open when you say "OK, google" to screen without clicking any button. Is there a way to set a "voice listener" just like onClickListener when a voice come and some Method will run.Or some other solution?Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuous listening for a keyphrase is supported by CMUSphinx, you can select any keyphrase. Download the demo here

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Comment: Thank you very much.I hava noticed Sphinx.Up to now I've achieved detecting environmen noise if the voice > 10db and the recognizer will be opened.But it takes about 500ms to close the environment detecting and open speech recognizer.I will try the method you said but I really dont like speaking some special words before I want to say a phrase.Is there any good solution?By the way,I want to build a robot who can talk to me easily.

Comment: Yes, you can use CMUSphinx for that too. You can configure it to accept phrases only with a tunable threshold.